# Flutter Desktop Auth

Tags: flutter, authentication, flutter-desktop

As we all know desktop application has no auth support so any one can help me with this.

```
Future<http.Response> signUp(
    String email,
    String password,
    ) async {
  final uri =
  Uri.parse("https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=$apiKey");
  final headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer token',
  };
  Map<String, dynamic> body = {
    "email": "xyz23@gmail.com",
    "password": "password",
    "returnSecureToken":true,
  };
  String jsonBody = json.encode(body);
  final encoding = Encoding.getByName('utf-8');

  http.Response response = await http.post(
    uri,
    headers: headers,
    body: jsonBody,
    encoding: encoding,
  );
  print(response.statusCode);
  print(response.body);

  jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
  // box.write("token", jsonResponse['refreshToken']);

  // oneTimeToken = jsonResponse['refreshToken'];
  // print(oneTimeToken);

  if (box.read('token') != null) {
    Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: 'Account Created Successfully',
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
        gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
        timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        textColor: Colors.white,
        fontSize: 16.0
    );;setState(() {
      loading = false;
    });
  } else if (response.statusCode != 200) {
    setState(() {
      loading = false;
    });


    Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: 'Account Already existing \n or missing data',
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
        gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
        timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        textColor: Colors.white,
        fontSize: 16.0
    );
  }

  return response;
}
```

Error:

```
flutter: {
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Invalid Credentials",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "authError",
        "location": "Authorization",
        "locationType": "header"
      }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_TYPE_UNSUPPORTED",
        "metadata": {
          "method": "google.cloud.identitytoolkit.v1.AuthenticationService.SignInWithPassword",
          "service": "identitytoolkit.googleapis.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am having this error can any one tell me what is this (OAuth 2 access token).I used this code on mongodb Works fine.

or

if anyone have any other solution it will be big help if provided.
thankyou.

get solution for flutter desktop auth.

Comment: You have a typo, `g,mail.com`

Comment: Sorry for that typo error it is just while writing here i have done this mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are NOT using OAuth 2.0 for your API, remove the authorization header from your sign up request and it should work.

```
final headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',

  //Remove this 'Authorization': 'Bearer token', 
};
```

Try it out on the command line using your API key

```
  curl --request POST \
  'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
    --header 'Accept: application/json' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --data '{"email":"test@test.com","password":"password123"}' \
    --compressed
```

https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v1/accounts/signUp

https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158862?hl=en&ref_topic=7013279

https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158849?hl=en&ref_topic=7013279

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#libraries

Comment: ya I tried this as well. Its showing same error.

Comment: please go through the links in the answer above and review how you have set up your API credentials. If you are using OAuth 2.0 for access to your APIs you need to make additional requests to retrieve an access_token before you can actually make the above sign up request.

Comment: thanks bro it got fixed. Sorry for the late replay. This code fixed it.                                                                                final headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      // 'Authorization': 'Bearer token',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    };

Comment: better solution: https://pub.dev/packages/firedart/example